# Inscribed triangle lengths from arc length

Tags: geometry, arc-length

Consider a circular arc, radius $r$, with endpoints $A$ and $D$. Arc $AD$ subtends an angle $\varphi$ < $\pi$. Thus, the arc length of $AD$ is $s_{AD} = r\varphi$. Place two points, $B$ and $C$ on $AD$ such that the arc measure $m(AB)$ is equal to the arc measure $m(CD)$. Let the angle subtended by $BC$ be $\theta$. Then, the arc length of $BC$ is $s_{BC} = r\theta$.

It is trivial to show that if the arc measure $m(BC)$ is $80$% that of $m(AD)$, then $5\theta = 4\varphi$. My question is as follows:

$$
$$

Consider the linear segments $\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{AD}$. Knowing the above relationship between arc lengths such that $5\theta = 4\varphi$, is there a direct relationship between the linear measures, i.e. does $\dfrac{m(\overline{AD})}{m(\overline{BC})}$ have a definition?

$$
$$

I have come to a few conclusions but I am not able to entirely eliminate the mention of the angles involved. I am seeking a direct relationship between linear measures.

Thank you.

Comment: You can compute the length of the linear segment inscribed in an arc using the angle and radius of the arc. You can then divide one segment's length by the other. The lengths of the segments are not proportional to the angles, and you will get different ratios for different values of $\theta.$ That is, when you write out the formulas for the lengths and divide one by the other, the radius will cancel out but the angle will not. Try it.

Comment: David, I have tried the problem. The best form that I have gotten this to resolve to analytically is:

$m(\overline{AD}) = m(\overline{BC})\cos(\dfrac{\theta}{4}) + \sqrt{(2r - m(\overline{BC}))(2r + m(\overline{BC}))}\sin(\dfrac{\theta}{4})$

$$
$$

I was only wondering if there was a clever way to eliminate the angle but it is seeming to not be an option.

Comment: I was thinking something like $m(\overline{AD})/m(\overline{BC}) = \sin(\phi)/\sin(\theta),$ then substitute either $\phi = \frac45\theta$ or $\theta = \frac45\phi$ in order to have only one variable.

Comment: I may have abstracted this more than necessary, I am going to return to it and see what I can come up with.